# PermissionError: [WinError 32] when using openpyxl

Tags: python

I am trying to move some excel files that in belongs to `C:/Users/computer/Desktop/file/cities` which names are matching in this excel file `cities.xlsx`. However i use idle to open the excel files with `engine = 'openpyxl'` i guess openpyxl causing some issues. Below i share the full code

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def fil(st):
    t = st.split('(')[0]
    t = t.replace(' ','')
    if 'ö' in t.lower():
        t = t.replace('ö','o')
    if 'ü' in t.lower():
        t = t.replace('ü','u')
    
    return t

df = pd.read_excel('eyalet2.xlsx',engine = 'openpyxl')
df.fillna('',inplace = True)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].map(fil)


def c():
    dire = os.getcwd()
    for filename in os.listdir(dire):
        fn = os.path.join(dire,filename)
        if os.path.splitext(fn)[1] == '':
            os.chdir(fn)
    for ex in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        yield os.path.splitext(ex)[0]

    olan = str()
fk = df.copy()

for cit in c():
    for col in df.columns:
        filt = df[col].isin([cit])
        if df.loc[filt,col].shape[0] >= 1:
            olan += f'{cit},'


for st in olan.split(','):
    for fl in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if st in fl:
            os.replace('C:/Users/niimet/Desktop/file/cities',
                f'C:/Users/niimet/Desktop/cities2/{st}.xlsx')
```

I am trying to move the excel files from `cities` to `cities2` however a nonrelevant error occuring. Because i never open the `Aachen.xlsx` file. Here i share the error. Error is occuring in the last for loop.

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
> because it is being used by another process:
> 'C:/Users/computer/Desktop/file/cities' ->
> 'C:/Users/computer/Desktop/cities2/Aachen.xlsx'

Comment: `os.replace` does not do what you think it does here. You seem to be trying to replace (rename) a file with a directory.

Comment: Which os method moves the file than ? When i searched in google this method it says will do as i want .

Comment: Yes, but not if you pass in a directory (`file/cities`) and a filename (`Desktop2/cities/something.xlsx`).

Comment: Also, you really should name your variables and functions better and separate this script into functional pieces. It seems you're reading a dataframe, and a list of files from some folder, to figure out a list of filenames for the move operation?

Comment: Also, since you use `os.chdir()` in `c()`, there's no real telling what `os.getcwd()` will be by the time you get to the final `os.listdir()`. Change your script not to use `chdir` and `listdir` – always play with absolute paths for your sanity's sake.

Comment: But still i didnt understand what causes this error. I know my code variable names are weird but how can i solve that?

Comment: The error in itself is caused by you trying to rename a directory (`cities`) to overwrite a file (`cities2/something`) while the script is being run from that directory `cities`. But that's hardly the only bug here.

Comment: But considering you're using `os.chdir()`, it's down to sheer luck whether `os.getcwd()` is what you expect it to be after the iteration process in `c()`.

Comment: Allright i have solved the problem, as you said i was overwriting i have changed to this. os.rename(f'{st}.xlsx',
                f'C:/Users/niimet/Desktop/cities2/{st}.xlsx')

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reworking of your code with better function names and no relative-path logic.

I can't tell whether it's perfectly correct, but it won't do anything destructive before you replace the last `print()` with an `os.rename()`.

```
import os
import pandas as pd


def filter_string(st):
    t = st.split("(")[0]
    t = t.replace(" ", "")
    t = t.replace("ö", "o")
    t = t.replace("ü", "u")
    return t


def get_eyalet_df():
    df = pd.read_excel("eyalet2.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
    df.fillna("", inplace=True)
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].map(filter_string)
    return df


def find_file_stems(root):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
        for filename in filenames:
            yield os.path.splitext(filename)[0]


def main():
    root = os.getcwd()
    df = get_eyalet_df()
    olan = set()
    for cit in find_file_stems(root):
        for col in df.columns:
            filt = df[col].isin([cit])
            if df.loc[filt, col].shape[0] >= 1:
                olan.add(cit)

    for filename in os.listdir(root):
        if any(fragment in filename for fragment in olan):
            source_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            dest_path = os.path.join("C:/Users/niimet/Desktop/cities2", filename)
            print(source_path, dest_path)
            # call os.rename(source_path, dest_path) if this seems correct


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```